# Raspbian Firefox-Sync Server - Can't find URL

Tags: synchronization, debian

I'm trying to create my own (local) firefox-sync server in combination with apache 2 on my raspbian (kernel version 3.10), but firefox-sync is complaining about my specified url ("ffsync.mraspberrypi.com")!

What I did:

---

1) First I followed this [tutorial](https://www.vegard.net/archives/9248/) for setting up the firefox-sync server (info: changed folder name from "syncserver" to "ffsyncserver" for own purposes).

Relevant changes to files:

(/opt/ffsyncserver/server-full/development.ini)

```
[server:main]
use = egg:Paste#http    # not sure about what to insert here!
host = localhost        # not sure about what to insert here!
port = 5000
use_threadpool = True
threadpool_workers = 60

[app:main]
use = egg:SyncServer
configuration = file:%(here)s/etc/sync.conf

[handler_syncserver_errors]
args = ('/opt/ffsyncserver/server-full/logs/sync-error.log',)
```

(/opt/ffsyncserver/server-full/etc/sync.conf)

```
[storage]
sqluri = sqlite:////opt/ffsyncserver/server-full/db/ffsync.db
quota_size = 25600

[auth]
sqluri = sqlite:////opt/ffsyncserver/server-full/db/ffsync.db
allow_new_users = true

[nodes]
fallback_node = http://ffsync.mraspberrypi.com

[smtp]
host = localhost
port = 25
sender = weave@mozilla.com

[reset_code]
sqluri = sqlite:////opt/ffsyncserver/server-full/db/ffsync.db
```

2) After that I installed Apache 2 as well as mod_wsgi by using this command

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Relevant changes to files:

(/etc/apache2/httpd.conf)

```
ServerName ffsync.mraspberrypi.com
```

(created file /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn)

```
ServerName ffsync.mraspberrypi.com
```

I also created a file /etc/apache2/sites-available/firefox-sync and linked it up in the folder /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/:

```
<Directory /opt/ffsyncserver/server-full>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ffsync.mraspberrypi.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mraspberrypi.com

    DocumentRoot /opt/ffsyncserver/server-full

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ffsyncserver_access.log combindes
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ffsyncserver_error.log

    WSGIProcessGroup ffsync
    WSGIDaemonProcess ffsync user=ffsync group=ffsync processes=2 threads=25
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/ffsyncserver/server-full/sync.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

As an example: After starting the apache2 server I can see the default-webpage by using the RPi's IP but it doesn't work by entering "ffsync.raspberrypi.com"!

If I want to use Firefox-Sync with the specified url above, it tells me that the given url is not valid!

So what's the problem?

Comment: Your client will try to find the IP address for ffsync.mraspberrypi.com on the internet. Unless you are the owner of the domain mraspberrypi.com, it will not find it. You will need to use a hostname for the server that your client can look up, probably in /etc/hosts.

Comment: i added the line "127.0.0.1 mraspberrypi" to the /etc/hosts file but still can only connect with the RPi's ip address!

Comment: The server name should be a single identifier, equal to the host name, say mraspberrypi. On the client, put the IP address of the RPi into the /etc/hosts file.